# How to make text disappear when HTML5 Video has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

The title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to have some text that says "Video Loading" and a 75% opaque background over the HTML5 video, and once it has completely loaded I want the text and background to disappear. How can I do that?

Thanks for you time and effort!
The page I'm trying to do this on is [jeffarries.com/videos](http://www.jeffarries.com/videos). Can provide code if needed.

---

The dup link is to a post trying to get the duration of the HTML5 video, I'm trying to have JavaScript change css properties when the HTML5 video is completely FINISHED loading into the browser.

Comment: Surely there are lots and lots of examples showing how to display a loading progress indicator for HTML5 videos. What have you tried and what are you getting hung up on?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864795/wait-until-an-html5-video-loads

Comment: @Quantastical I'm new to JavaScript and don't know the markup well, and was hoping for a finished/near finished solution.

Comment: @Jeff check out the HTML5 video 'onloadeddata' or "canplaythru' events and that will be when you'd want to hide your overlay - https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Great Link, thanks a lot!!!  It looks like "canplaythrough" would be better, could you please give me some JavaScript code that would change the CSS `display: block;` to `display: none;` for HTML element with id "video_loading"?? I don't know JavaScript well, thanks!

Comment: have a look at this answer to get you started ... change the event, and rather than reset the source change the CSS for the video_loading element - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284751/how-to-stop-playing-a-video-element-and-return-it-back-to-its-original-state/27286015#27286015

Comment: @Offbeatmammal That's great! However, how do I get it to respond to "canplaythrough"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this JavaScript code to hide my HTML element with id "video_cover" by changing CSS `display: block;` to `display: none;` when the HTML5 video element "myVideo" fires `canplaythrough`:

```js
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("video_cover");
       e.style.display = 'none'
};
</script>
```

Resources:
W3Schools [canplaythrough](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp) JavaScript event.

Sorry if my JavaScript terminology is bad, I'm just learning it!

---

Thanks again @Quantastical and @Offbeatmammal for all your help!