# Can HTML video poster be shown at close of video without using jquery or javascript

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have a page on which there are multiple videos (informational site). I use the basic HTML/CSS player markup - no Javascript/jQuery. I just don't know enough about either.

My posters show up for each video when the page itself is refreshed, but once a video is played (or paused) the poster does not reappear. Is it possible to recall the poster somehow as part of the simple HTML player - or is the only choice to try to find Javascript/jQuery code and try to make it work?

TRIED THIS - but still no change

```
<div id="video-player">
<div id="video-tree">
<video id="myVideo" poster="someImage.png" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="videoONE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
</div>

<div id="video-player">
<div id="video-tree">
<video id="myVideo" poster="someImage.png" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="videoTWO.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Then the function I am trying to use is the one mentioned in first comments.

```
<script>
var vid=document.getElementById('myVideo');
vid.addEventListener("ended", resetVideo, false);

function resetVideo() {
// resets the video element by resetting the source
this.src = this.src
}   
</script>
```

Tried the option in the first answer submitted but that made no change either. Am I understanding actually what has to happen? When the page loads, and someone clicks on the video, the variable vid is capturing that specific element id and then waiting to get an "ended" event. When the video ends, that event occurs, then the "resetVideo" function runs. It resets the src (videoONE or videoTWO) and if all is working properly, the initial screen of the video should reappear. Am I right in understanding that this function doesn't actually touch the poster - it is really just resetting the video. So if the actual video first screen is a blue screen - that's what people would see - and not the original poster/splash screen - right? So is it the poster I actually need to reset?

Comment: without Javascript? no. With Javascript, pretty easy, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284751/how-to-stop-playing-a-video-element-and-return-it-back-to-its-original-state/27286015#27286015

Comment: I don't understand enough JavaScript to really understand the answer you posted but will dig in and see if I can figure it out. I think I'm just too green to use stackoverflow.

Comment: if you can show us a sample of the page I can show you how to integrate it...

Comment: That is super generous of you to offer. I will first try to integrate it myself (I'll have to support it if it breaks so I need to try to understand how it works if I can) and if I can't figure it out I'll show a sample and get your guidance. Thanks!

Comment: @SBradford Your perseverance is much appreciated. Many new users are a lot less focused on actually learning than you are.

Comment: @Feathercrown - thx - trying to improve.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal  Stuck and need nudge in right direction. My div has an id but the source line does not <source src='theVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4> I added an id <source id="myVideo"....> and then used the function you mentioned. But no change. To show you my code, should I use codepen, or can I type right in this comment section?

Comment: Oh wait - I see that I should modify my original question. I'll do that right now.

Comment: your two videos both have the same ID, so it's probably getting confused where to attach the handler. have you tried with just one video? if each video has a different id and you do `document.getElementById('myVideo1').addEventListener("ended", resetVideo, false);` for each that might work better

Comment: Let me give that a try. I tried just one video with the code that is in the answer that was provided below, but that did not work. Let me try just the one and see. Thank you!

Comment: Adding the specific id let it reset - so that's great. Unfortunately, it looks like it also lost the page buffer because it comes up with an "Invalid Source" error on the video control bar. If I refresh the page, that goes away - so I think that is a buffer issue (not 100%). But at least I know now that the individual ID works in terms of getting back to the original state of the video. I will see if the answer down below, where it was suggested that a this.load() was needed might overcome the buffer issue. Thank you!

Comment: The this.load() didn't fix. Well, at least this brings me MUCH closer to what I need to accomplish. Thank you so much. I'll keep working on it and if I find a way to get past this error, I'll post the info here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

1. When you have more than one video, `getElementById()` will not work for all of them, it's designed to access **only one element because an id is unique.** You cannot have 2 videos with the id of `myVideo`, you cannot have 2 divs with the id of `video-player`, nor can you have 2 divs with the id of `video-tree`. Change the div ids into `class` and the `myVideo` into `myVideo1` and `myVideo2`.
2. You must either add an event to each video which is wasteful and redundant, or you can collect the videos into a list (an array, NodeList, etc).

Snippet 2 will:

1. Collect all 4 video elements into a NodeList and convert it into an array.
2. Using the array method `forEach()` it will take each video in the array and add an `eventListener` to it (a little wasteful but if I make more efficient it'll be more complicated).

See Snippet 2

---

### Old

I don't recall any way to invoke the `poster` attribute without JavaScript. But it looks as if you already use JavaScript anyhow so you need to use the [`.load()`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp) method.

**Snippet 1**

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('vid');

vid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  this.load();
}, false);
```

```html
<video id='vid' poster="http://placehold.it/430x250/0e0/111?text=POSTER" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005612.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Snippet 2**

```html
<div class="video-player">
  <div class="video-tree">
    <video id="myVideo1" poster="http://placehold.it/430x250/000/fff?text=POSTER I" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="video-player">
  <div class="video-tree">
    <video id="myVideo2" poster="http://placehold.it/430x250/0ff/000?text=POSTER II" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005610.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="video-player">
  <div class="video-tree">
    <video id="myVideo3" poster="http://placehold.it/430x250/e00/fff?text=POSTER III" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="video-player">
  <div class="video-tree">
    <video id="myVideo4" poster="http://placehold.it/430x250/fc0/000?text=POSTER IV" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005612.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var videos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('video'));

  videos.forEach(function(vid, idx) {
    vid.addEventListener('ended', resetVideo, false);
  });

  function resetVideo(e) {
    this.load();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about why this is different than the function I was using? What does "this.load" accomplish? Is it more specific to the video that has been clicked and is thus reloading that specific poster? Do I then not need to use the reset video function as in my example? (Sorry - as I said in my original post - I am very green in regard to javascript and am trying to really understand.)

Comment: Tried this and no change. The video poster does not reappear when the video concludes. Just the blue blank screen appears.

Comment: OK  added to my question to make it more clear what I am trying to accomplish - what has worked/hasn't - and what I think the javascript is doing.

Comment: `load()` is what you need to invoke when `.src` is changed, or you need to reset it in general. As a side effect, the rest of the video element's attributes are reset as well. In the `resetVideo()` function replace `this.src = this.src` with `this.load()`. If you want to have more than one video per page, then you must ask another question because what you have now is geared to only one. To explain exceeds this thread.

Comment: Did you test the Snippet by clicking the blue button that is labeled:"Run code snippet"?

Comment: I did test the snippet and it did not work - even when I was using with just one video on the page. I will try exploring the this.src = this.load() and see if I can figure out something. Thank you.

Comment: I may have it. I need to run some more tests, but after fixing the id situation per the recommendation by @Offbeatmammal and then using all his function EXCEPT changing the final line to just this.load(), it seems to be reverting back to the original poster AND is not losing the source information already loaded previously. I'll test some more this evening but this looks very promising.

Comment: Ok, wait...you're telling me after clicking the **blue button** and running my function, you say it's not working? What browser are you using? *"changing the final line to just this.load(), it seems to be reverting back to the original poster AND is not losing the source information already loaded previously."* of course it'll keep source and revert back to poster. Has ever occurred to you that's all you really needed?

Comment: See the edit, click the **blue button** this time. and play all videos at the same time or individually

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As I stated at the very beginning, I am green to the gills in regard to javascript. So yes, it occurred to me that I just needed to swap out the poster but I had no idea how to do that. I'm really grateful for everyone's suggestions as it helped me understand what was needed, how to get there, and now I understand how to support it if it breaks AND your last suggestion gives me more to explore in terms of how to use for multiple videos. I don't know how to mark your last snippet as the answer - but it should be so marked.

Comment: That's great. Remember use class as much as you can, use id sparingly and **ids are unique** , never put an id on more than one element. Use arrays to access multiple elements. Happy coding.

Comment: To swap out a poster directly, try `this.poster = "http://imgh.us/Lenna.png"` you'll probably have to follow it with: `this.load()`

Comment: Thank you! I changed up my markup immediately and my css file. I'm going to work with your array suggestion as well. I just saw another of your posts on a response about video controls and working on that as well now! So so so so much to learn!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked - a combination of two of the suggestions above. A big thank you to @Offbeatmammal and to @zer00ne.

In the body:

```
<div class="video-player">
<div class="video-tree">
<video id="myVideo1" poster="someImage.png" width="430" height="250" controls>
<source src="someVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
</div> <!-- end video-tree class -->
</div><!-- end video-player class -->
```

Function

```
<script>
var vid=document.getElementById('myVideo1');
vid.addEventListener("ended", resetVideo, false);

function resetVideo() {
// resets the video element by reload of video
this.load()
}   
</script>
```

I recognize that this is NOT an elegant solution for multiple videos on one page as it would require additional scripting to identify the video being called. We are ultimately resolving this "upstream" by insuring that, going forward, our media team creates the videos so that they do not end with a blank screen. For our videos that are older (limited number), this solution is working.